# How do I analyze the clause pattern 'move into the apartment'?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, grammatical-roles

How can I identify the form and function of each constituent in this sentence?

> They moved into the apartment together.

I don't know which one of these two possible analyses correct:

1. They (noun, subject)
   moved (verb, predicate)
   **into the apartment** (**prepositional** phrase, non-central complement)
   together. (adverb phrase, adjunct)
2. They (noun, subject)
   **moved into** (verb, predicate)
   the apartment (**noun** phrase, non-central complement)
   together. (adverb phrase, adjunct)

Comment: "They" (NP subject). "Moved into the apartment together" (VP Predicate); "Into the apartment" (PP complement of "moved"); "together" (prep as adjunct).

Comment: May I ask why the word 'together' is considered as a prep instead of an adverb?

Comment: It's the modern way of classifying it, see here: [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/together). You can treat it as an adverb if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: Once you go with interpretation 2, *the apartment* looks like the object: I occupied the apartment.

Comment: Right. Both right. As usual, there's more than one way to parse a sentence, and most people can do either one and still come out describing the same thing. That's the fact that defeats general rules -- you don't hafta do things the way the teachers say. There's lotsa different ways that work just as well. For some folks, it's obvious that (1) is the usual parse, for others it's (2), and plenty of others don't notice any difference, since they both work.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: @arlo I disagree with the last comment. Neither of your analyses are right. The Predicate VP is the whole _moved into the apartment together_. Within the VP is the PP "into the apartment". Would you like a full answer instead of just comments?

Comment: That would be great! And actually, the full sentence is 'They moved into the apartment together three years ago'. I am wondering if you could help me check whether my analysis is correct.                                                                              
Here's my current analysis: They - form: NP, function: S;
Moved - form: Ve, function: P;
into the apartment - form: PP, function: Cx;
Together - form: AdvP/PP, function: A;
Three years ago - form: NP, function: A

Comment: @arlo Not quite: as I said before the predicate is the whole of _moved into the apartment together_. "Three years ago" is part of the predicate but it's a PP, not an NP. I'll do a tree shortly.

Comment: Answer now posted.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *They moved into the apartment together three years ago.*

[image]

Note that some would treat "together" as a complement rather than as an adjunct.

Comment: Why is *3 years ago* not an adjunct there?

Comment: I have the same question. Why is '3 years ago' not an adjunct in this sentence?

Comment: @BillJ Thank you so much!!